# What does the Observer see during Length Contraction in special relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

so i was reading this http://physics.bu.edu/py106/notes/Relativity.html and its says at 95% the speed of light the spaceship crew would have aged 3.122 years while people on earth 10 years. Ok so lets not think about a planet 9.5 light years away, lets just talk about moon. So a spaceship goes to the moon (and back) at 95% speed of light, I dont know how to calculate but lets assume the time taken by spaceship is X and time noted by people on earth looking at the spaceship is Y (of course X will be less then Y). What I want to know is this: generally, when we look at things speeding up we recognize/notice the speed up, but talking about our time Y it is clear to me that observing the spaceship all the time while it goes to the moon and back we will testify that the spaceship took time Y, which means that as the speed of the spaceship was increasing in real, we are unable to observe the speed up beyond a certain point? At about what speed do we stop realizing that its speeding up so that to justify earth time Y that earth observers will see?

Hope I asked it right its a bit complex to write about this.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use Earth time to measure proper time of the ship. These are two different times so there is no contradiction, and no missing link you need to find. Observer on Earth will observe one time and observer on the ship another, just like two travellers setting from one point and walking to another can walk for different amounts of time to get there (if they take different routes). Here the travellers are moving in spacetime, apart from this the analogy is quite close.

Comment: as I said its difficult to explain, I am not finding any contradictions, I am trying to understand it, my question: what speed will I observe, in the sense that when I see someone going from slower to faster speeds in normal conditions, I can see and realise that its speeding up, not in this case, the 95% speed of light. Given a distance and speed you can figure out time taken (simple), in this case I will testify that spaceship was not going fast but they were? I mean I will "see" the speed that it has taken Y time for them to go & come back, which means I cant detect the real speed?

Comment: There is no real speed, only the speed you observe, and that's subjective to you. Perhaps it would help to be more specific on how you would measure the speed, but any sane way of measuring would show you that spaceship is travelling slower than the speed of light. Maybe what you should focus on is how the acceleration is achieved? If the rocket is propelled by jet engine its proper acceleration will be constant, and you will end up with [Hyperbolic motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)). So constant (proper) acceleration will not look constant to you.

Comment: Regarding my last statement, see the last equation in this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527263/lorentz-non-invariance-of-3-acceleration/527280#527280