# Relation between proper acceleration and 4-acceleration

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, inertial-frames

A rocket with 4-coordinate $(X^\alpha)$ is accelerating and $\tau$ is its proper time.

4-velocity $V^\alpha=\frac{d X^\alpha}{d\tau}$ and its 4-acceleration $A^\alpha = {V^\alpha}_{;\beta}V^\beta$.

For the observer in the rocket, $V^\alpha$ can be taken as $(1,0,0,0)$.

Since $A^\alpha V_\alpha=0$, we get $A^0=0$.

I'm wondering the relation between $(A^1, A^2, A^3)$ and the proper acceleration that the observer in the rocket **feels**.

Reading the wikipedia & other stack exchange questions, my guess is as the following:

- Let a test particle is in the rocket but there is no external forces on it.
- Therefore it follows a geodesic, while the observer binded to the rocket does not.
- The observer measures the velocity $u$ of the test particle.
- Then the proper acceleration $\gamma^{3}\frac{du}{dt}$ is equal to  $(A^1, A^2, A^3).$

## Question

1. Is my guess correct? (if not, what is the correct relation?)
2. If so, how can we derive this relation?

Please give me help.

Comment: The proper acceleration is the scalar $A = g_{\mu \nu}A^{\mu}A^{\nu}$. If we write $\mathbf{a}$ as the coordinate acceleration $(a_x, a_y, a_z)$, and $a$ as the magnitude of $\mathbf{a}$, then the equation $A = \gamma^3 a$ relates the proper acceleration $A$ to the magnitude of the coordinate acceleration $a$.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Thank you. Could you tell me how to derive it?

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527263/lorentz-non-invariance-of-3-acceleration/527280#527280

Comment: @Cryo, it does!!! Thank you!!